# Php artisan migrate - syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T string )

Tags: php, laravel-6, laravel-migrations

Code of migration file Code. syntax error.

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {$table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->bigIncrements('id');
     $table->string('title')->nullable();
     $table->integer('order_id')->default('0');
     $table->unsignedBigInteger('test_type_id');
     $table->foreign('test_type_id')->references('id')->on('test_types');
     $table->enum('status',['active','deactive','draft'])->default('draft');
     $table->timestamps();
});
```

Already run composer update. Let me know what I am missing.

If the question is duplicate I am happy to remove it.

Comment: remove one `$table->bigIncrements('id')`

Comment: default('0'); => default(0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into the migration file and try again 
Just remove 'bigIncrements' one time.

```
 Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->bigIncrements('id');
 $table->string('title')->nullable();
 $table->integer('order_id')->default(0);
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('test_type_id');
 $table->foreign('test_type_id')->references('id')->on('test_types');
 $table->enum('status',['active','deactive','draft'])->default('draft');
 $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: default('0'); => default(0); as @Ronak Dhoot said